# How do I get a single piece of data from Quickbooks Online?

Tags: java, python, clojure, quickbooks-online

I've got a client who uses Quickbooks Online for accounts, and he wants to be able to read data from it programmatically. We're using Clojure, so any solution in Java will work, or http gets etc can be made directly if necessary.

They've got what appears to be a nice RESTFUL interface to their stuff, and a java library for accessing it, but I can't make head or tail of their documentation: https://developer.intuit.com/docs?redirectid=accounting, which all seems to be about webapps and OAuth and other stuff.

All I want to be able to do is get, say, a single customer record.

Can anyone point me to the simplest possible Hello World type program, in any language? (Preferably Java or something easy to read like python)

I'd imagine that what I'm looking for would look something like:

```
import quickbooksapi

username='fluffy'
password='doom'

cus=quickbooksapi.get_customer(username,password,id=4)

print(cus)
```

or something?

Or have I just got the wrong end of some gigantic stick here?

Comment: some links to the part of the documentation you are trying to follow and your first attempt at calling them from clojure would make this question easier to answer.

Comment: Well, that's the thing! The documentation is so impenetrable that I haven't managed to make any attempt. This looks like it might be a good place to start: https://developer.intuit.com/docs?redirectid=accounting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks the best available documentation:

https://developer.intuit.com/hub/blog/2016/04/25/quick-start-to-quickbooks-online-rest-api-with-oauth1-0

It's a recent blog post by a Quickbooks developer, showing how to get Oauth keys and then use curl to access the REST API.

It seems that you have to pretend to make a SaaS app in order to get one bit of gubbins and then there's another thing where you can get the rest of the gubbins.

After that you can use curl, putting all the gubbins in the headers. (The postman extension for chrome that he uses can generate curl commands and equivalents in many other languages)

It works exactly as advertised (6th August 2016).

That's enough. I can take it from there.